# Error message "Error:BrokenCount>0"

Tags: updates, package-management, synaptic

I get the red symbol with the white line through it at the top of my screen.

It says `Error:BrokenCount>0`

Now i go into the **Synaptic Package Manager** and click on the *Broken Dependecies* and get this:

`linux-image-generic-pae  3.2.0.52.62`

Now I know the problem occured when I tried to update and didn't have enough storage space in order to do it.

How do I go about fixing it and getting Ubuntu healthy again?

I followed rajagenupula instructions. However, the issue still remains.

Does having a USB memory stick plugged in cause problems?

Terminal reported back with this:

```
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
[sudo] password for skunk: 
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
mv: cannot stat `/var/lib/dpkg/status': No such file or directory
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get clean
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae but it is not  installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]           
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [84.9 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [2,494 B]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [28.0 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [1,803 B]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [331 kB]
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4,620 B]
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [84.5 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2,633 B]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]       
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [150 kB]
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]        
Get:23 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1,299 B]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en [1,253 B]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [51.9 kB]
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]        
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]      
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B] 
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]  
Get:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]  
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex [3,706 B]    
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,676 B]
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex [2,596 B]
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex [2,922 B]
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [416 kB]     
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [7,031 B]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [95.3 kB] 
Get:38 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [8,358 B]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [707 kB]
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
Get:41 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [219 kB]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.0 kB]
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3,564 B]
Get:44 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2,605 B]
Get:45 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2,461 B]
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2,850 B]
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en [726 kB]       
Get:48 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en [93.4 kB]
Get:49 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2,395 B]
Get:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3,341 kB] 
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [310 kB]
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8,064 B]
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2,637 B]
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [126 kB]
Fetched 19.3 MB in 2min 4s (155 kB/s)                                          
Reading package lists... Done
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae; however:
Package linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic (3.2.0-52.78) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.2.0-52-generic   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-52-generic
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-52-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on Wubi system
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
done
Setting up linux-image-generic (3.2.0.52.62) ...
Setting up jockey-gtk (0.9.7-0ubuntu7.10) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-generic-pae
skunk@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae linux-image-generic-pae
Suggested packages:
fdutils linux-doc-3.2.0 linux-source-3.2.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
The following packages will be upgraded:
linux-image-generic-pae
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 38.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 113 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae i386 3.2.0-53.81 [38.3 MB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main linux-image-generic-pae i386 3.2.0.53.63 [2,358 B]
Fetched 38.3 MB in 3min 58s (160 kB/s)                                         
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae.
(Reading database ... 1018276 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae (from .../linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae_3.2.0-53.81_i386.deb) ...
Done.
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-53-generic-pae (3.2.0-53.81) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 3.2.0-53-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-53-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
Warning: No support for locale: en_US.utf8
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 3.2.0-53-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 3.2.0-53-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-53-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-53-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-52-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-52-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-48-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-44-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-44-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-44-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-43-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-43-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-39-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-33-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-33-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-32-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-31-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-30-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-30-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-29-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-29-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-27-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-27-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-25-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-25-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic-pae
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-24-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-24-generic
Found Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Skipping Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on Wubi system
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2
Skipping Windows 7 (loader) on Wubi system
done
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae; however:
Package linux-image-3.2.0-52-generic-pae is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I think `sudo apt-get -f install` would be enough. Give it a try and report back.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the output of `apt-cache policy linux-image-generic-pae` and `apt-cache rdepends linux-image-generic-pae`?

Comment: No use ubuntu.pastebin.com and give me the complete log. part of it doesnt help much.

Comment: I've updated to show the full log of what happened when I followed your instructions Rajagenupula.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal  with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>and paste these commands one after one

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

credit goes to [Ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068352&page=2&s=914df8b493bcd415fee9545d730d1e4f)

Comment: He updated his question.

Comment: So should I look at the quicker solution of re-installing UBUNTU to get it working again? Save the contents of my HOME folder and move on to a later version of UBUNTU.